# Fabric initial deployment

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

i'm a little bit stuck with a problematic.

I'm trying to use continuous integration to build my app and deploy them to Crashlytics.

I've tried a lot of different solutions (Fastlane, Gradle, manual execution). Theses solutions are working when my application was already deployed with the Fabric.app and the Android Studio Fabric Plugin.

But, when i'm trying to deploy a new application, everything is working fine, i've got this message at the end :

> fastlane.tools finished successfully

One the Fabric dashboard, i'm unable to find my application.

Is there any way to build and deploy applications for the first time without Fabric.app and Android Studio Fabric Plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! But you will need to integrate Crashlytics, and build and run the app. We need to detect both a build and run event per bundle ID or package name in order to provision your app in our system.

Thanks!